# where does "yum list" get the data from?

Tags: yum

Does `yum list` command get data from the yum repository or from the redhat page via internet?

Back ground:

I have updated yum repository for httpd only (x86_64 with updated httpd rpm)

```
createrepo -update /repository/yum/x86_64
```

Then I have reverted the original repository file

```
createrepo -update /repository/yum/x86_64_20170116
```

when I check the httpd ver of x86_64_20170116 the httpd version is outdated(original state)

```
ll x86_64_20170116/Packages/ httpd*
```

however, when I enter below commands, the httpd version is up to date

```
yum list available | grep httpd
```

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you do a `yum update` before the `yum list`?

Comment: Sorry Zumo, i DID do yun update for httpd(download only) but downloaded to a specific folder first, then I have taken backup of the current repository, then recreated repository with the httpd ver.

Comment: # yum update httpd --downloadonly --downloaddir=/home/yumupdate/20170116/ httpd

# cd /repository/yum/
# cp -rp x86_64/ x86_64_20170116

# cp /home/yumupdate/20170116/*.rpm /yum/repository/x86_64/Packages/.
# createrepo -update /repository/yum/x86_64

Answer (score 0):

By default 'yum list' without any options will list all packages in all the repositories and all the packages installed on your system. Note: 'yum list all' and 'yum list' give the same output.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys,

the parent server goes out to fetch data from redhat repo with "yum list" command.
it also has the local repo.

when i punched "yum list" command on the child server, it went to fetch the data from the local repo stored in the parent server.

this Q was probably too basic ... thank you all again for your time and support.